# When is the earliest point in which i can start a new cycle

Tags: disgaea-2

In Disgaea 1 and 4 that i am sure of there are points during the game in which you can get an alternate ending and start a new cycle, it is apparently something from Disgaea 3

so i am wondering, when is (if any) the earliest point in which i can start a new cycle for Disgaea 2: Dark Hero Days

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get an alternate ending and start a new cycle by losing to Axel in any of his fights, the first one being in stage 1-4.

Comment: Yep, that's worked, though i had to grind some Mana to create a bunch of prinnys to loose easier (PRINNY THROWING!)